# Case statement with multiple records

Tags: nested, case-statement

For a requirement I need to create a SQL which should check the data from Table A.
If data exists in table a, query should return that result.

If data doesn't exists on table A, query should check data in table B and return the result.

I tried to use the case statement for this requirement, but I guess case statement is allowed for a single record.

Any help for this is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.